# Adding jTextfields Values in java using netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtextfield

i want to add the values of two jTextfield and show the results in another jTextfield. how do i do this programatically.

example i have  jTextfield called "MonthlyDep" and another jTextfield called "NewAcc"

how do add the values of the two and show it in a jTextfield called "rslts"

Thank You.

Comment: Well from your question style, i am assuming that you haven't tried anything first. **Please** try something on your own, show us your nice effort and what have you tried until now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in button click (ActionListener) write this code..

```
rslts.setText((Integer.parseInt(MonthlyDep.getText())+Integer.parseInt(NewAcc.getText()))+"");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
rslt.setText(String.valueOf(Integer.parseInt(MonthlyDep.getText()) + Integer.parseInt(NewAcc.getText())));
```

see [Javadoc of JtextField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html)